# What is the significance of the birds in several scenes?

Tags: analysis, exodus-gods-and-kings

In *Exodus: Gods and Kings*, we see many birds in various scenes.  I want to know if there is any specific cause or intention.

I think there is no need for giving example. It is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

I have provided two examples of different scenes from this movie containing birds.

The birds in these scenes represent something completely different.  The intent for adding birds to these scenes was to dramatize a significant story line and provide powerful visual effects.

1. **Scene depicting high priestess reading the entrails of a bird**:

   This scene is very early in the movie.  A high priestess cuts open a white bird and reads the entrails.

   This scene is obviously implying the prophetic importance of the entrails of this particular type of [bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodus:_Gods_and_Kings):

   > In 1300 BC, Moses, a general and member of the royal family, prepares
   >   to attack the Hittite army with Prince Ramesses. A High Priestess of
   >   Sekhmet (the war goddess) divines a prophecy from animal intestines,
   >   which she relates to Ramesses' father, Seti I. He tells the two men of
   >   the prophecy, in which one (of Moses and Ramesses) will save the other
   >   and become a leader. During the attack on the Hittites, Moses saves
   >   Ramesses' life, leaving both men troubled. Later, Moses is sent to the
   >   city of Pithom to meet with the Viceroy Hegep, who oversees the Hebrew
   >   slaves. Upon his arrival, he encounters the slave Joshua, who is the
   >   descendant of Joseph, and Moses is appalled by the horrific conditions
   >   of the slaves. Shortly afterwards, Moses meets Nun, who informs him of
   >   his true lineage; he is the child of Hebrew parents who was sent by
   >   his sister Miriam to be raised by Pharaoh's daughter. Moses is stunned
   >   at the revelation and leaves angrily. However, two Hebrews also
   >   overhear Nun's story and report their discovery to Hegep.
2. **Scene depicting the "parting" of The Red Sea**:

   There are 300,000 birds shown in this scene as the water recedes. 
   This is simply birds being attracted to the many fish that are left
   exposed in the sand.

   An excerpt from an interview with Jessica Norman, VFX [Supervisor](http://www.artofvfx.com/exodus-gods-and-kings-jessica-norman-vfx-supervisor-mpc/):

   > > Through the scene we added over 300,000 crowd birds that are attracted
   > >     by the fish that gets exposed with the draining of the sea. The birds
   > >     helped to add extra frenzy and drama to the scene and worked as an
   > >     extra atmospheric layer. Typically we would add a lot of dust to most
   > >     large crowd shots, this time we added birds.

One scene displays a bird being utilized for prophetic value while playing a role in a major plot point.

One scene depicts a realistic dramatization utilizing visual effects to enhance the viewing experience.